# Time series forecasting for the next three months

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, seasonality

[image]
I have a time series dataset that records the number of passengers per day. Based on this data, I need to make predictions for the **next three months at the monthly level.**

The provided plot illustrates the number of passengers in different areas of the city since 2019. Each line represents the passenger count observed in a specific area. The data also exhibits **weekly seasonality**. However, I am currently facing the following issues:

- what models can be used to predict values on the long run?
- How can I predict the values for the new areas (since Nov-2022) in the next three months, considering the limited available data?
- Should I treat each area as a separate time series ?
- As evident from the plot, there is noise and a downward trend between certain dates,how
  can I smooth out this noise without affecting the chosen prediction model?

I am new to time series forecasting.